# Dataset for plant identification

Tags: data-request, images, wikidata, biology

I'm looking for a plant identification dataset (to train a plant identification system) that is free or not too expensive to use and has plant images, specifically garden plants. Just wondering if anyone came across such a thing? Or perhaps could you point me toward where to look for it?

So far I came across a few databases but they all are not free to use.

Answer (score 1):

This is for the leaf disease detection: https://www.kaggle.com/emmarex/plantdisease

I haven't checked this myself but https://www.kaggle.com/c/leaf-classification/notebooks this kaggle competition might help you!

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/One-hundred+plant+species+leaves+data+set - This is an UCI dataset, the files will also lead you to the papers which have used it. Please do cite it when you use it!

Let me know if you find anything else! Please do upvote if it helps :)